# Why do I get two return values here?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int main(){

int recurse(int);
int a=recurse(0);
printf(" return %d",a);
}
```

First one:

```
 int recurse(int c){
//printf("%d", c);
if(c<10){
   recurse(c+1);
}else{
return(c);
} 
}
```

second one:

```
int recurse(int c){
//printf("%d", c);
if(c<10){
   recurse(c+1);
}
return(c);
}
```

In the first one..I get return value of 10 while in the second one I get a return value of 0. Why do I get two different values and why 0??

Answer (score 2):

In fact this function

```
int recurse(int c){
//printf("%d", c);
if(c<10){
   recurse(c+1);
}else{
return(c);
} 
}
```

has undefined behaviour because it returns nothing in case when `c < 10`

This function

```
int recurse(int c){
//printf("%d", c);
if(c<10){
   recurse(c+1);
}
return(c);
}
```

always returns the value of argument `c` independently of the value itself. The function has unconditional return statement and returns its argument. As it was called with argument equal to 0 then it returned it.:)

A correct function will look the following way

```
int recurse( int c )
{
    return c < 10 ? recurse( c + 1 ) : c;
}
```

Of course it could be written simpler without the recursion :)

```
int recurse( int c )
{
    return c < 10 ? 10 : c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because without the else in the second one the return statement isn't part of the if statement. So that means it will do the if loop and then return c independent of the if loop.

Answer (score 0):

The first function exhibits undefined behavior since you don't have `return` statements in all branches of execution.

The function needs to be:

```
int recurse(int c){
   if(c<10){
      return recurse(c+1); // Add return
   }else{
      return(c);
   } 
}
```

The second function returns `c` no matter what happens in the `if` block.

```
int recurse(int c){
   if(c<10){
      return recurse(c+1);  // Add return
   }
   return(c);
}
```